# Twilio & Whatsapp / SMS for multi tenant environment - can it be done

Tags: twilio, sms, whatsapp, twilio-api

We have a multi tenant app and we want to make an option available to customers to be able to send / receive whatsapp messages and sms messages.

Ideally we would have a way to allow the customers to connect their Whatsapp business account and with SMS we would provide them a number dedicated to them.

For billing we would get the billing per customer and auto bill them monthly using our own billing system.

My question is this something you can do with Twilio programmatically as in the setup of the customer account / folder / partition etc - provision a number OR connect Whatsapp and then retrieve the billing.

Each customer would have to be completely isolated but could be under the one master account which is ours.

Has anybody done something like this? Any help would be great I reached out to Twilio sales but heard nothing back.

Michael

Just designing and exploring options.

Comment: Hi there! Just wanted to share this blog post that outlines some of the process around onboarding as a WhatsApp ISV with Twilio: https://www.twilio.com/blog/whatsapp-business-api-onboarding-for-isvs